# Create a hash dynamically and assign each key a different value

Tags: ruby, hash

How can I dynamically create a hash, giving each of its key a different value? For example:

```
hash = {}
(1..9).each{|key| hash[key] = ' '}
```

creates a hash with keys 1 to 9, where every key has the same value, a space. How can I do the same, keys 1 to 9, but with each key holding a different value.

Comment: `hash[key] = SecureRandom.hex` would assign random string to each key

Comment: @AmitPatel: There is still a slight chance that two keys get the same value.

Comment: This question is confusing. What do you want the values for the hash to be exactly?

Comment: @grenierm5 let's say the hash values are a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

Comment: @undur_gongor: "slight chance" - that's quite an overstatement. While true in theory, for all practical purposes this chance is zero.

Comment: Is it a homework of some kind or do you actually need it in a real app?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Overstatement? The probability is about 9e-345 (modulo arithmetic error). That's a "slight chance" in my book.

Comment: @undur_gongor: very very slight :)

Answer (score 1):

If the values do not matter and just have to be different:

```
hash = Hash[(1..9).zip(1..9)]   
# => {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>4, 5=>5, 6=>6, 7=>7, 8=>8, 9=>9}

hash = Hash[(1..9).zip('a'..'z')]   
# => {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c", 4=>"d", 5=>"e", 6=>"f", 7=>"g", 8=>"h", 9=>"i"}
```

For bigger hashes, performance can be improved by not creating intermediate arrays:

```
hash = (1..1000).inject({}) { | a, e | a[e] = e; a }
```

Comment: let's say the hash values are a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

Comment: Are those variables or string literals?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for dynamic hash creation with distinct key values.

```
hash = {}
(1..9).each_with_index{|key,index| hash[key] = index}
1..9
>> hash

hash
{1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>4, 6=>5, 7=>6, 8=>7, 9=>8}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p (1..9).zip(("a".."i").to_a.shuffle).to_h
# => {1=>"a", 2=>"d", 3=>"b", 4=>"h", 5=>"e", 6=>"g", 7=>"f", 8=>"i", 9=>"c"}
```

Comment: As `zip` is a method of `Enumerable`, the first `to_a` is not needed, I think.